# Password strength function return only one vlaue

Tags: javascript, html, passwords

I am new with Javascript and ,I'm trying to write a password strength function.
But each time I enter a password, it returns only one value ("very strong").
I completely confused !!
Here is my Code :

```
function pwd_Validation()
    {
        var strength = new Array();
        strength[0] = "Blank";
        strength[1] = "Very Weak";
        strength[2] = "Weak";
        strength[3] = "Medium";
        strength[4] = "Strong";
        strength[5] = "Very Strong";


        var password = document.getElementById('pwd')

        if (password.length < 1)
            var score = 1;


       else if (password.length < 4)
             score = 2


        else if (password.length >= 8 && password.value.match(/[a-z]/))
                 score = 3;


       else if (password.length >= 8 && password.value.match(/[a-z]/) && password.value.match(/[A-Z]/) && password.value.match(/[0-9]/))
                score = 4;


       else  (password.length >= 8 && password.value.match(/[a-z]/) && password.value.match(/[A-Z]/) && password.value.match(/[0-9]/) && password.value.match(/.[!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,?,_,~,-,£,(,)]/))
                score = 5;


        document.getElementById('spnPwd').innerHTML = strength[score];

        if ( password.value = "")
            document.getElementById('spnPwd').innerHTML = strength[0];
            document.getElementById('spnPwd').style.color="#FF0000"

        if ( strength[score] == 1)
            document.getElementById('spnPwd').innerHTML = strength[1];
            document.getElementById('spnPwd').style.color="#FF0000"

        if ( strength[score] == 3)
            document.getElementById('spnPwd').innerHTML = strength[3];
            document.getElementById('spnPwd').style.color="#FFCC00"

        if ( strength[score] == 4)
            document.getElementById('spnPwd').innerHTML = strength[4];
            document.getElementById('spnPwd').style.color="#19D119"

         if ( strength[score] == 5)
            document.getElementById('spnPwd').innerHTML = strength[5];
            document.getElementById('spnPwd').style.color="#006600"

    }
```

HTML code :

```
Password :   <input type="password" id="pwd" onblur="pwd_Validation()" />
                <span id="spnPwd" class="pwd_Strength" ></span><br />
```

Comment: `password.value = ""` assigns a variable but is used in a `if` clause

Comment: You also have a logic problem.  Your score variable is not set to anything if your password length is 4, 5, 6 or 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were several coding errors and logic errors.  I would suggest this rewrite that makes the following fixes/improvements:

1. Get the actual password value and use its length instead of using the length of the password DOM element.
2. Handle the case of the length between 4 and 7 (a case your logic skipped)
3. Sequence the regex tests in the right order so it actually finds the proper score
4. Corrected the punctuation regex
5. Fix else logic problem
6. Put the colors into a parallel array.
7. Declare the strength strings in a more efficient/compact way.
8. Give your score a default value so it is guaranteed to have a value.
9. Don't repeat regex tests more than once
10. Use `regex.test` because it's more efficient than `regex.match` when all you want to know is if it matched
11. Pull the desired color value from the array rather than an `if` statement for every score
12. Only fetch the `spnPwd` DOM element once
13. Changed the numeric regex to `\d`
14. Use braces on all if/else statements for safety

And the suggested code:

```
function pwd_Validation() {
    var strengths = ["Blank", "Very Weak", "Weak", "Medium", "Strong", "Very Strong"];
    var colors = ["#FF0000", "#FF0000", "#FFCC00", "#FFCC00", "#19D119", "#006600"];
    var score = 0;
    var regLower = /[a-z]/, regUpper = /[A-Z]/, regNumber = /\d/, regPunctuation = /[.,!@#$%^&*?_~\-£()]/;

    var password = document.getElementById('pwd').value;
    if (!password) {
        score = 0;
    } else if (password.length < 2) {
        score = 1;
    } else if (password.length < 4) {
        score = 2;
    } else if (password.length <= 7) {
        score = 3;
    } else {
        // length is >= 8 in here
        if (regLower.test(password) && regUpper.test(password) && regNumber.test(password)) {
            // if it also has punctuation, then it gets a 5, otherwise just a 4
            if (regPunctuation.test(password)) {
                score = 5;
            } else {
                score = 4;
            }
        } else {
            // if doesn't have upper, lower and numbers, then it gets a 3
            score = 3;
        }
    }
    var spanPwd = document.getElementById('spnPwd');
    spanPwd.innerHTML = strengths[score];
    spanPwd.style.color = colors[score];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's an `if` missing from the last `else` so it's parsed like this:

```
...
else {
    (password.length >= 8 && password.value.match(/[a-z]/) && password.value.match(/[A-Z]/) && password.value.match(/[0-9]/) && password.value.match(/.[!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,?,_,~,-,£,(,)]/))
}

score = 5;
```

It's a good habit to always use brackets in control structures.

Comment: This is not the issue, see my answer

Comment: @Manishearth Not the *only* issue, you mean. Even by applying your answer this bug would still need to be fixed. (This is in fact why the end result is that score ends up always being 5.)

Comment: oh oops. Fixed in my answer then, thanks

Comment: Actually there are a *lot* more issues in the OPs code now that other answers are coming in... The whole truth is the combination of all the answers.

Comment: See my answer. He same the number in scope and then he ask strength[score] for the number. that is the main error i think

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to convert the password field to its value:

```
var password = document.getElementById('pwd')
```

should be 
    var password = document.getElementById('pwd').value

In your original case, `password.length` is undefined, and all comparisons with it evaluate to false. (So the final `else` is executed)

Also, your last `else` block

```
   else  (password.length >= 8 && password.value.match(/[a-z]/) && password.value.match(/[A-Z]/) && password.value.match(/[0-9]/) && password.value.match(/.[!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,?,_,~,-,£,(,)]/))
            score = 5;
```

should be

```
   else  if(password.length >= 8 && password.value.match(/[a-z]/) && password.value.match(/[A-Z]/) && password.value.match(/[0-9]/) && password.value.match(/.[!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,?,_,~,-,£,(,)]/))
            score = 5;
```

Aside from that, please use braces in your ifs. It is bad practice to have code like this:

```
if(...)
 ...
else if(...)
 ...
else
 ...
```

This is better:

```
if(...){
 ...
}else if(...){
 ...
}else{
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've pushed your code through [jsbeautifier.org](http://jsbeautifier.org/). This has reindented your code according to how a javascript interpreter would actually run it. Please notice how your if statements are **not** running the code you think they are.

```
function pwd_Validation() {
    var strength = new Array();
    strength[0] = "Blank";
    strength[1] = "Very Weak";
    strength[2] = "Weak";
    strength[3] = "Medium";
    strength[4] = "Strong";
    strength[5] = "Very Strong";

    var password = document.getElementById('pwd')

    if (password.length < 1) var score = 1;
    else if (password.length < 4) score = 2
    else if (password.length >= 8 && password.value.match(/[a-z]/)) score = 3;
    else if (password.length >= 8 && password.value.match(/[a-z]/) && password.value.match(/[A-Z]/) && password.value.match(/[0-9]/)) score = 4;
    else(password.length >= 8 && password.value.match(/[a-z]/) && password.value.match(/[A-Z]/) && password.value.match(/[0-9]/) && password.value.match(/.[!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,?,_,~,-,£,(,)]/))
    score = 5;

    document.getElementById('spnPwd').innerHTML = strength[score];

    if (password.value = "") document.getElementById('spnPwd').innerHTML = strength[0];
    document.getElementById('spnPwd').style.color = "#FF0000"

    if (strength[score] == 1) document.getElementById('spnPwd').innerHTML = strength[1];
    document.getElementById('spnPwd').style.color = "#FF0000"

    if (strength[score] == 3) document.getElementById('spnPwd').innerHTML = strength[3];
    document.getElementById('spnPwd').style.color = "#FFCC00"

    if (strength[score] == 4) document.getElementById('spnPwd').innerHTML = strength[4];
    document.getElementById('spnPwd').style.color = "#19D119"

    if (strength[score] == 5) document.getElementById('spnPwd').innerHTML = strength[5];
    document.getElementById('spnPwd').style.color = "#006600"    
}
```

To take some particular examples out:

```
if (strength[score] == 5) document.getElementById('spnPwd').innerHTML = strength[5];
document.getElementById('spnPwd').style.color = "#006600"
```

Likely you intended this to be:

```
if (strength[score] == 5) {
    document.getElementById('spnPwd').innerHTML = strength[5];
    document.getElementById('spnPwd').style.color = "#006600"
}
```

Also:

```
else(password.length >= 8 && password.value.match(/[a-z]/) && password.value.match(/[A-Z]/) && password.value.match(/[0-9]/) && password.value.match(/.[!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,?,_,~,-,£,(,)]/))
score = 5;
```

You probably meant:

```
else if (password.length >= 8 && password.value.match(/[a-z]/) && password.value.match(/[A-Z]/) && password.value.match(/[0-9]/) && password.value.match(/.[!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,?,_,~,-,£,(,)]/)) {
    score = 5;
}
```

---

The actual issue you mention in your code is because of the second conditional that I've pulled out. The line `score = 5` is **not** part of any conditional, and will always be run (for reasons mentioned above). This is why you're always seeing that the passwords are "Very Strong".

Answer (score 0):

you save to the var **score** and then you ask **strength[score]**.  `if (strength[score] == 3)`

then you are missing some  { } in the second part of the code!

in the last part you can use

```
switch(score) {
 case 1: ... break;

...
 default: ... break;
}
```